# How to fix Behavioursubject subscription issue from service to component

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular7, rxjs6

I am using the Behavioursubject in my application i subscribed the Behavioursubject using async pipe and I have subscribed in my component.

issue: when ever i am trying to update the data in Behavioursubject the data is updating in the Behavioursubject. the component subscription is not getting updated. at the time of application initiation subscription getting executed. after initiation based on change i am updating the data in the service the data is updating in the service but the subscription inside the component is not updating.

I tried multiple ways like changing the service registration to root module and that too not worked

Here is my component code:

this is the method subscription called.

```
 ngOnInit() {
 this.getnotifications();
 }
 getnotifications() {
     this.notifications.getjsnotifications('all');
    this.notifications.jsnotifications.subscribe(data => {
      console.log("came after the update");
      this.jsnotifications = data;
    });
   }
```

Here is the code of service:

```
  public jsnotifications = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor(){
   this.getjsnotifications("all");
  }

  getjsnotifications(type){
    this.http.get<Config>(`${environment.JS_API}/jobseeker/notifications/getJobSeekerNotifications?notificationType=`+type).subscribe(data =>{
     console.log(data.map.notificationsVo);
      this.jsnotifications.next(data.map.notificationsVo);
      this.jsnotifications.subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      this.testbehaviour.next(data.map.notificationsVo);
      console.log("data updated");
    });
  }
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would recommend, re-phrasing your question. Its really hard to follow. Also, I dont see where you are using the service in your component to make the http request. The ngOnInit() function does not use your service.

Comment: Please provide a stackblitz link to be able to help you better

Comment: ok there are multiple modules in this reproducing the issue is very difficult

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is right and should work, despite these two strange things:

- Subscribing to an HTTP request in a service is a strange pattern
- The subscription inside the HTTP subscription will be duplicated on every HTTP request

The problem is very likely coming from the way you declared the service, that caused two different instances to be created.

Be sure declare your service with **only one** of the following methods:

- With this annotation `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`
- In the `providers` section of the root module

Comment: i imported in root module data is coming and updating but the component subscription is not working

Comment: constrictor? I think there's a boa in your code what is mean by this

Comment: just a bad joke to point out your typo: you wrote `constrictor` instead of `constructor`. Not sure if you pasted that from your code, or if you mistyped in the question

Comment: that's i manually typed. i tried many possibilities i haven't got any sollution